# Get back to first fragment of view pager when clicked on button in second fragment of view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using view pager and in that I am having three fragments. In my second fragment I am having button clicking on which take you to the first fragment.

I am new with the fragment. So please give me your valuable suggestions and links for this.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On click of the button in the second fragment, communicate from your fragment to your parent activity that the first fragment is to be shown. You parent activity can then call a function in your view pager which shows the first fragment.

Define an interface in the fragment -

```
OnCategorySelectedListener mCallback;
 // Container Activity must implement this interface. 
    public interface OnBackSelectedListener {
        // Called when the user clicks back button
        public void onBackSelected();
    }
```

In onAttach(), link the callback -

```
try {
            mCallback = (OnBackSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnBackSelectedListener");
        }
```

When the back button is clicked, call the callback interface method -

```
mCallback.onBackSelected();
```

In your view pager, implement the onBackSelectedListener interface.

Comment: I don't have any parent activity. I am making app in which I use view pager consists of 3 fragments. And each fragment consists of different things.

Comment: you can define a interface in your fragment and assign the viewpager as the callback. The view pager should then implement the interface method. See updated answer.

Comment: @ Mukesh Soni what do you mean by mCallback? Is it ref or obj of which class?

Comment: @ Mukesh Soni But what if i want to move from first fragment to third fragment. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I guess that within your adapter you are saving a reference to the pager. You can do viewPager.setCurrentItem(num) to jump to a particular page. Page starts from 0.